# How to return 'blank' using Sum function in Sql, if Sum is resulting 0 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I am using Sql Server 2008. I am adding some column value using Sum function. Like the code below:

```
 SELECT 'RCOAuthorizer LMS',
'' AS Consumer_Loan,
'' AS Auto_Loan,
'' AS Credit_Card,
SUM(CASE
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Loan Amendment' THEN sq2.user_count
       ELSE ''
   END ) AS Loan_Amendment,
SUM(CASE
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Pre-Payment' THEN sq2.user_count
       ELSE ''
   END ) AS Pre_Payment,
SUM(CASE
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Corporate Credit card' THEN sq2.user_count
       ELSE ''
   END ) AS Corporate_Credit_card,
'' AS Auto_Payment_Release,
'' AS Car_Mulkiya
 FROM
( SELECT 'RCOAuthorizer' AS ws_name,
       'Loan Amendment' AS loan_type,
       COUNT (DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno) AS user_count,
             a.user_id AS user_id
FROM BM_LMS_DecisionHistoryGrid a
INNER JOIN
 ( SELECT m.bpm_referenceno
  FROM BM_LMS_EXTTABLE m
  WHERE m.request_type = 'Loan Amendment' ) sq1 ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
WHERE workstep_name = 'RCOAuthorizer'
GROUP BY a.user_id
UNION SELECT 'RCOAuthorizer',
            'Pre-Payment',
            COUNT (DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno), a.user_id
FROM BM_LMS_DecisionHistoryGrid a
INNER JOIN
 ( SELECT m.bpm_referenceno
  FROM BM_LMS_EXTTABLE m
  WHERE m.request_type = 'Pre-Payment' ) sq1 ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
WHERE workstep_name = 'RCOAuthorizer'
GROUP BY a.user_id
UNION SELECT 'RCOAuthorizer',
            'Corporate Credit card',
            COUNT (DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno), a.user_id
FROM BM_LMS_DecisionHistoryGrid a
INNER JOIN
 ( SELECT m.bpm_referenceno
  FROM BM_LMS_EXTTABLE m
  WHERE m.request_type = 'Corporate Credit card' ) sq1 ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
WHERE workstep_name = 'RCOAuthorizer'
GROUP BY a.user_id ) sq2
GROUP BY sq2.ws_name
```

The above query will return Sum of all the numbers available in 'a' column. But in case, there is no record, then it will return '0' as result.

I require that if there is no record, it must show blank instead of showing '0'. How to handle the same.

Comment: By "there is no record" do you actually mean there is a record where column a is null? If there is no record, there would be no sum too....

Comment: No record means 0. In the above code, it will never return Null as I am already handling it by using isnull() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you don't need an `ISNULL` with a back value of `0` (*the neutral for adding*) inside a `SUM` aggregate, as the `SUM` already ignores `NULL` values. So `SUM(ISNULL(Column, 0))` is equal to `SUM(Column)` (but different from `ISNULL(SUM(Column), 0)`!).

Seems that you want a `VARCHAR` result instead of a numeric one. You can solve this with a `CASE`.

```
Select 
    CASE WHEN Sum(a) = 0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Sum(a)) END
from 
    table;
```

If you don't want to repeat the `SUM` expression:

```
;WITH SumResult AS
(
    Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Sum(a)) AS SumTotal 
    from table
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN R.SumTotal = '0' THEN '' ELSE R.SumTotal END
FROM
    SumResult AS R
```

Keep in mind that in these both cases, if there is no record to calculate the sum from, the result will be `NULL`.

---

**EDIT**: There is no point in adding `''` inside your `SUM`, as it's converted to 0 to be able to sum. The solution is still the same as I posted before.

Change

```
SUM(CASE
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Pre-Payment' THEN sq2.user_count
       ELSE ''
   END ) AS Pre_Payment,
```

for

```
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Pre-Payment' THEN sq2.user_count END) = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SUM(CASE WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Pre-Payment' THEN sq2.user_count)) END AS Pre_Payment,
```

Comment: I have updated the code with actual code. In this, the prepayment column displays '0' as there is no value. I want to return blank. Please check.

Comment: @MdKamranAzam edited, check now. The solution still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this ( use *isnull* again ):

```
Select isnull(Sum(isnull(a,0)),0) from table_;
```

I used `table_` instead of `table`, because `table` is a reserved keyword.

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28378/2)

Comment: I have updated the code with actual code. In this, the prepayment column displays '0' as there is no value. I want to return blank. Please check.

Comment: @MdKamranAzam your question text still says : `But in case, there is no record, then it will return '0' as result.`